# How do i set the cadet or input value to be in same position as placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

Using HTML, CSS and to create a countdown timer, currently the cadet is on the extreme left of the input box, I want the text to start appearing in the same position as the placeholder then I type the value.

```css
.name-box {
  width: 100%;
}

.name-box input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.name-box input::placeholder {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: gray;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="details-box">
  <h2>Enter Your Details</h2>
  <form action="">
    <div class="name-box">
      <input type="text" id="firstName" required placeholder="Name of Recepient">
    </div>

    <div class="date-box">
      <input type="text" for="inputDate" id="inputDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
    </div>

    <div class="message-box">
      <textarea placeholder="Message you want displayed" for="message" id="message" cols="50" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <input type="reset" id="resetButton" value="Reset">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move CSS rules responsible for `font-size` and `padding` to input:

```
.name-box{
  width: 100%;
}
.name-box input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; 
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px ;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.name-box input::placeholder{
  color:gray;
}
```